# R grouping with Select the rows with Limited

Tags: r

The sample data frame

```
grp = c(1,1,1, 1,1,2,2,2,2,2, 2,2) 
val = c(2,1,5,NA,3,NA,1) 

dta = data.frame(grp=grp, val=val)
```

The results should look like this:

```
# The max number of count is 3
grp count 
 1    3
 1    2
 2    3
 2    3
 2    1
```

Comment: grp count 
 1    3
 1    2
 2    3
 2    3
 2    1

Comment: To make a data frame you need equal number of rows in both columns. Right now it is different 12, 7. Please update your question with correct data.

Comment: @Pj_, not necessarily but I think in this case yes.

Comment: @sotos one of the main constrains of an R data frame is that each column must be of the same length. There are other constraints as well, but that's a pretty big one. The code block provided by the OP also shows they've done no work at all for this problem or for making this reproducible on SO.

Comment: @hrbrmstr There are ways to create data frames with unequal columns (filling with NAs, etc), it is not prohibited. That's what I mean. As for the second part of your comment, I couldn't agree more.

Comment: `NA` is a legal value. The columns are still equal length.  They are not "unequal" and it's a pretty bad misnomer to refer to them that way in any language that supports the data frame concept.

Comment: What I m saying is that if you are given two vectors of unequal length then you can still convert them to a data frame after you make them equal of course.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way with `base R`. We first count the repeated measures with `rle`. Then use a custom function that combines `3` with the remainder of the division. Finally we combine to form a new data frame:

```
grp = c(1,1,1, 1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)

fun3 <- function(x) c(rep(3, floor(x/3)), x %% 3)
len <- rle(grp)$lengths
ans <- lapply(len, fun3)
cbind.data.frame(grp=rep(unique(grp), lengths(ans)), count=unlist(ans))
#   grp count
# 1   1     3
# 2   1     2
# 3   2     3
# 4   2     3
# 5   2     1
```